# Как сделать кастомному контролу кастомные евенты, по типу onMouseClicked?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

В общем при создании кастомного контрола, с его проперти я справился, чтоб и `SceneBuilder` их видел. Встал вопрос как сделать контролу кастомный евент, чтоб можно было в `fxml` указать его, как и `onMouseClicked=""`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Для большего понимания вопроса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Полагаю надо смотреть в сторону конструктора `FXMLoader` с собственным `BuilderFactory`. Расширить `JavaFXBuilderFactory` не выйдет, он с меткой final.

Comment: @Maxim это уже наверное слишком, достаточно сделать ему `eventProperty` - любое проперти и он его увидит, но вот как именно созданть кастомный евент, чтоб на него ещё и подписывать через проперти я не знаю, и поиски чет не увенчиваются успехом

Comment: А на что вы хотите, что бы ваш event срабатывал? Мышки, тачи, клавиатуры, по сути все события которые могут понадобиться уже есть.

Comment: @Maxim например на изменение одного из параметров/проперти и т.п

Comment: Если это проперти, то у нее есть собственный changeListener, добавьте к нему вызов метода, который вы хотите в onMouseClicked и никакие нагромождения в xml верстке не потребуются

Comment: @Maxim я не хочу ничего в onMouseClicked мне он не нужен, мне не нужно событие клика, мне нужно кастомное событие смены проперти контрола. Почему именно так не стоит упоминания здесь, ибо описывать архитектуру, классы и т.п. излишне. Суть имеено в кастомном евенте, и только так, никакие обходные пути тоже не помогут. Как то так)

Answer (score 1):

В контроллере надо создать кнопку с именем `id` кнопки в `fxml`, в методе `initialize()` этой кнопке можно повесить `EventHandler`, `setOnAnction`, `setOnMouseClicked` и всё, что угодно.
Другой вариант: кнопке в `fxml` можно добавить атрибут `onAction` с именем вызываемого при нажатии метода в контроллере таким образом: `onAction="#onClickMethod"`.

**Controller**

```java
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    public void onClickMethod() {
        button.setText("Thanks!");
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, mouseEvent -> button.setText("Thanks!"));
    }
}
```

**fxml**

```
<Button fx:id="button" onAction="#onClickMethod" text="Click Me!"/>
```

[Статья](https://devcolibri.com/javafx-2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-button/)

Comment: Вопрос был немного в другом, ни как понавешать листнеров и действий на евент, а как создать именно свой евент, и к нему проперти, чтоб из fxml их было видно и именно чтоб можно прям прям в fxml написать `<Pane onMyCustomEvent="myFunction()"/>` например. Но всё равно спасибо, где-нибудь кусочек кода обязательно пригодится.